# screen in screen, detach only last one

Tags: linux, unix, gnu-screen

I have strange issue on my hands.

I have opened (GNU) screen for one serial console and in that same console I have opened another screen to another serial console.

It was working but I am now unable to detach the last one without detaching the 1st one.

I know that this is due to same configuration for both screen.

Is there some way to detach the last screen without detaching the first one?

Any advice is most welcome and appreciate. Thanks

diagram:

```
SCREEN (1st one) [ ... SCREEN (last one) [ ... --- current view --- ... ] ... ]
```

Comment: You could try to change the control character of one of the sessions by using C-a : escape ... more info at https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Command-Character

Comment: daniel@ yes I know, but when happens and you do not have any other option for next let us say ~12 hours, you need to find solution on situation as is.

Comment: Maybe he was thinking about using the `colon` command, `^A:` to reconfigure the control character at runtime. Sounds a bit risky, I admit - worth practicing elsewhere before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to press `<CTRL-A> <A> <CTRL-D>` sequentially. `<CTRL-A> <A>` sends control symbol to the inner screen while `<CTRL-A>` - to the outermost one.

Comment: this works: <CTRL-A> <A> <D> do the trick, thanks for point that out about ctrl+a a

Comment: Ooops, <CTRL-A><CTRL-\> close the screen, not detach it, my mistake!